# Почему элементарный javascript с jsfiddle не работает в локальном монофайле?

Tags: javascript

Ни в одном браузере.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>блабла</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Scada" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arsenal" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

(function(document) {
    "use strict";

    var hidden_el  = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-content"),
        control_el = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-content");

    if (hidden_el.length < 1 || control_el.length < 1) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the elements
    hidden_el  = hidden_el[0];
    control_el = control_el[0];

    control_el.onclick = function() {
        var element_classes = (" "+hidden_el.className+" ").replace(/[\n\t\r]/g, " "),
            remove_class    = "slide-down",
            add_class       = "slide-up",
            is_showing      = element_classes.indexOf(" "+remove_class+" ") > -1;

        if ( ! is_showing) {
            // Switch variable values
            remove_class = [add_class, add_class = remove_class][0];
        }

        // Remove the previous class (if present) and add the new class
        hidden_el.className = (element_classes.replace(" "+remove_class+" ", "") + " "+add_class+" ").trim();

        return false;
    };
})(document);


</script>
<style type="text/css">
.slide-up, .slide-down {
    max-height: 0;            
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.slide-down {            
    max-height: 10em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="toggle-content">Show / Hide</div>
<hr />
<div class="hidden-content slide-up">
   Ribeye fatback tongue spare ribs cow doner salami short ribs pork chop pork loin. Salami andouille kielbasa hamburger. Bresaola hamburger capicola ball tip, brisket tri-tip meatloaf flank pork loin ribeye spare ribs. Turkey ground round pork chop, leberkas short ribs jowl doner tongue pork loin.    
</div>
<hr />
<div>
    Some content here
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что Вы вызываете Ваше IIFE в `head`, где ни одного элемента, к которым обращается код, еще не существует.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  "use strict";
  ...
});
```

---

> Ни в одном браузере.

Это же отлично! Значит, когда Вы почините код, он заработает во всех браузерах!